# CUPS have no configuration file

Tags: linux-mint, cups

I removed the cups from my Linux Mint and now when I reinstall it I cannot see the configuration file anymore:

```
/etc/cups $ ls
interfaces  ppd  raw.convs  raw.types
```

How can I restore everything? I need to reinstall the linux mint from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to purge your cups package from the system with

`apt-get purge cups`

and after reinstall it with

`apt-get install cups`

here you can find all the info you'll need on how configure your printer.

https://wiki.debian.org/SystemPrinting

Comment: I did the purge and after install again that's the files I see on cups folder:
/etc/cups $ ls
interfaces  ppd  raw.convs  raw.types  snmp.conf

Comment: what would you like to do? add a printer?